# CIFS mount from bash script with dynamic IP from variable

Tags: bash, mount, scripts, raspberrypi, cifs

Trying to mount Windows directory from bash script

**Following works**

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.2/Shared /home/pi/windowshare -o user=some_user,password=some_pass
```

**Following works**

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=192.168.1.2
sudo mount.cifs //$IP/Shared /home/pi/windowshare -o user=some_user,password=some_pass
```

**EDIT: Following doesn't**

Worked with the variable created in bash script. But, does not work with variables from sourced file.

```
#!/bin/bash

source /boot/.env
echo $IP

sudo mount.cifs //$IP/Shared /home/pi/windowshare -o user=some_user,password=some_pass
```

**Error:**
Unknown erroruld not resolve address for 192.168.1.2

Tried escaping as `\/\/$IP` but then it throws "bad UNC"

Comment: @steeldriver sorry that was a typo. I have edited it. Variable actually comes form sourced file

Comment: Does the error really read `Unknown erroruld not resolve`? if so, I would be checking the `/boot/.env` file for DOS-style (CRLF) line endings

Comment: Yes, It does read that way. will try checking line endings once